# JSP c:forEach error: property not found

Tags: jsp

It's a weird problem I have faced long time and couldn't resolve. Hope someone here can point out my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Basically, I was using c:forEach tag in JSP to loop through the properties. However, It showed "Property not found error" for list property inside model class. Here is code of properties inside model class:

```
private String stnID = new String();
private String stnShortName = new String();
private String stnDesc = new String();
private List<RailDeviceInfo> railDeviceInfoList = new ArrayList<RailDeviceInfo>();
```

And I knew that JSP only work with the getter method, here is my getter for list property:

```
public List<RailDeviceInfo> getDeviceList()
{
    return this.railDeviceInfoList;
}
```

Finally, here is my JSP code:

```
<c:forEach items="${railList}" var="station">
   <c:out value="${station.stnID}" />
   <c:out value="${station.stnShortName}" />
   <c:out value="${station.stnDesc}" />

   <c:forEach items="${station.railDeviceInfoList}" var="device">
       <!-- can not found station.railDeviceInfoList -->
       <c:out value="${device.id}" />
       <c:out value="${device.name}" />
   <c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getter is `getDeviceList()`, so the property is `deviceList`, and not `railDeviceInfoList`:

```
<c:forEach items="${station.deviceList}" var="device">
```

The EL doesn't care about the private fields of your class. It cares about its JavaBean properties.

Comment: Thank you very much JB Nizet! I learn new stuff.I thought EL care bout the private field of model class.

Answer (score 0):

jstl find the getRailDeviceInfoList() method with in your case 
but it is not exist.
you should use station.deviceList instead of station.railDeviceInfoList

Comment: Yes, nrvmodi. Both JB Nizet and you are right about it. I was too nerd to program that way.